# Cannot compile protoc-generated (C++) classes

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm currently having some troubles with compiling protobuf-generated C++ code.
`protoc` runs correctly and doesn't show any warnings, however when I try to compile the generated C++ code so I can build a static library, g++ shows me the following message:

> CanInfo.pb.cc:107:5: error: ‘::protobuf_BusType_2eproto’ has not been declared
>     107 |   ::protobuf_BusType_2eproto::AddDescriptors();

What I've been able to gather so far, this is some issue with my BusType enumeration, which looks something like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package MyPackage;

enum BusType {

    ProprietaryBus = 0;
    OpenBus = 1;
    UnknownBus = 2;

}
```

This enumeration is included by a message called CanInfo which looks something like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package MyPackage;

import "BusType.proto";

message CanInfo {

    int32 interfaceId = 10;
    bool isConnected = 20;
    BusType busType = 30;

}
```

As I mentioned before, `protoc` compiles these files "correctly" (without error).
The version used to compile the protos is **protoc 3.6.0**.
This is the portion of C++ code generated by `protoc`:

```
::google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(
      descriptor, 248);
::google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(
    "data_containers/device_data/CanInfo.proto", &protobuf_RegisterTypes);
::protobuf_BusType_2eproto::AddDescriptors();
//           ^ error occurs here
```

Searching through the code, the only mention of the `protobuf_BusType_2eproto` namespace is the line above. 
The compiler version used to compile the C++ code is `powerpc-linux-gnu-g++-6 (Ubuntu 6.4.0-17ubuntu1) 6.4.0 20180424`.
Changing the G++ version used to version 8 or 9 **doesn't** change this behaviour.

I've tried cleaning the build directory many times, and I've tried switching to a different protobuf version (3.4.0), however this also resulted in many compiler errors, mostly because the `protoc` version was too old.

Building each file individually also doesn't change the behaviour.

What is causing this behaviour? I've not had issues using Protobuf until now.
Has anyone experienced this before and knows a handy trick?

---

**EDIT**
Could this possibly be caused by the way I'm calling `protoc`?

```
###
# Re-compile protos
###
set(BUILD_PROTOS True)
set(PROTOBUF_COMPILER protoc)
if (BUILD_PROTOS)
    function(BUILD_PROTOS)
        foreach(PROTO ${PROTOS})
            message("Compiling ${PROTO}...")
            execute_process(
                COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_COMPILER} ${PROTO_DIRS} "--cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" ${PROTO}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
            )
        endforeach()
    endfunction()

    ###
    # Compile all protos
    ###
    BUILD_PROTOS()
endif()
```

Comment: I think `protobuf_BusType_2eproto` namespace should be used in `BusType.pb.h`, which should be included in `CanInfo.pb.h`. Are you sure there are no compile errors about missing include?

Comment: There are no other errors than the one posted above.
The namespace used in BusType.pb.h is `protobuf_data_5fcontainers_2fdevice_5fdata_2fBusType_2eproto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though I've fixed the issue. 
There is apparently a bug in the `protoc` compiler, where importing files in the same directory causes this strange behaviour when compiling single files each time.
When compiling multiple files at once, `protoc` produces an error stating that the enum value has already been defined in another file and issues the following note:

> device_data/BusType.proto:15:5: Note that enum values use C++ scoping rules, meaning that enum values are siblings of their type, not children of it.  Therefore, "ProprietaryBus" must be unique within "MyPackage", not just within "BusType".

The googling intensified and I came across this old [Google Code post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/hjSrItXxnsc) from 2012:

> To protocol compiler "bar.proto" and "x/bar.proto" are two proto files
>   although they are pointed at the same physical file.
>   Using 'import "x/bar.proto"' is the right fix.

The workaround (or fix) was simply to add the entire path relative to the working directory of `protoc`.

```
import "data_containers/device_data/BusType.proto";
```

In CMake, this looks like the following now.

```
message("Compiling protos...")
execute_process(
  COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_COMPILER}
  ${PROTO_DIRS} "--cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" ${PROTOS}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

This has so far fixed my problem, I will edit my answer if any new information comes up.
Maybe this will be useful to someone else.